# Iframe apply styling to its content and then show the webpage to the user

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I am using an Iframe to display a webpage to the user. It goes like

```
<iframe
         src="http://localhost:3000"
         width="100%"
         height="100%"
         id="myframe"
         style={{ border: 'none' }}
         ref={iframeRef}
         onLoad={() => onLoadFunction()}
         />

 const onLoadFunction = () => {
    var x = document.getElementById('myframe')
    var y = x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument
    const header = y.document.querySelector('.header')
    header.style.display = 'none'
    console.log(header, 'x123')
  }
```

now i am able to load my content and apply the styling `header.style.display = 'none'` but the header shows at first and then gets taken off the UI after 1-2 seconds, is there a way i could remove header first and then show the content to the user once my entire styling is applied?

Attached the screenshots below

1. Iframe loads the webpage [image: with header]
2. Later applies the styling and removes the header as needed [image: without header]

Comment: You could perhaps switch to a DOMContentLoaded handler instead of load, if the iframe loads external resources that could make a bit of difference.

Comment: Or make the iframe itself invisible to begin with (using `visibility` rather than `display`, otherwise you might get issues with it loading in the first place), and then make it visible on load, after you hidden the header.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by displaying your own site content within an iframe?

Comment: @Yogi thats just an example of how do i solve this issue

Comment: This might apply: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/320245) "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem."